# Accessing values in NGRX state programmatically

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have an NGRX state setup that is an object of values. The value keys are numbers (1-5) with a boolean value.

**state.ts**

```
export interface State {
  1: boolean;
  2: boolean;
  3: boolean;
  4: boolean;
  5: boolean;
}

export const initialState: State = {
  1: true,
  2: true,
  3: true,
  4: true,
  5: true,
}
```

I also have an action that is getting passed the object number value through it. So in my reducer, I am grabbing the number value, finding that value in the object, and switching the boolean. However, I am running into an issue where I can't select the object key in my reducer function without actually typing out the physical number.

**action.ts**

```
export const changeButtonState = createAction(
  '[Bingo Actions] Change Button State',
  (payload: number) => ({payload}),
);
```

**reducer.ts**

```
export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(BingoActions.changeButtonState, (state, action) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      action.payload: !state[action.payload],
    };
  })
);
```

How can I access the number value of an object without having to physically type the number in the reducer function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot that this was an object in the state and just needed to adjust the reducer to add a bracket around the action.payload assignment.

**Updated reducer.ts**

```
export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(BingoActions.changeButtonState, (state, action) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      [action.payload]: !state[action.payload],
    };
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Computed property names for your object keys**  - https://ui.dev/computed-property-names/

```
export const stateKeys = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  ...
```

```
export interface State {
  [stateKeys.one]: boolean;
  [stateKeys.two]: boolean;
...
```

Then to access the property with a computed name inside your reducer, the syntax is:

```
state[stateKeys.one]
```